# StackExchange.Redis failing to connect with Mono in Mac OS X

Tags: c#, mono, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to run a very simple Redis client on Mono in Mac OS X with the following options:

```
var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions() 
{
    EndPoints =
{
    { "localhost", 6379 },
},
ResolveDns = true,
KeepAlive = 180
};
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions, tw);
```

It fails to connect. Here is the trace:

```
localhost:6379,keepAlive=180,resolveDns=True

Using DNS to resolve 'localhost'...
'localhost' => 127.0.0.1
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 127.0.0.1:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:01 to respond...
127.0.0.1:6379 faulted: UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING
127.0.0.1:6379 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
No masters detected
127.0.0.1:6379: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:03:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
127.0.0.1:6379: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=1, wr=0, async=1, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=1
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
Starting heartbeat...
```

I've tried with and without ResolveDNS and specifying the IP address directly. Tried several ports as well. Server is running and is reachable by redis-cli.

StackExchange.Redis version="1.0.289" targetFramework="net45"

Redis-64 2.8.9

### Update

StackExchange.Redis version="1.0.297" targetFramework="net45", same problem but different log

localhost:6666,keepAlive=180,resolveDns=True

```
Using DNS to resolve 'localhost'...
'localhost' => 127.0.0.1
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 127.0.0.1:6666 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
127.0.0.1:6666 faulted: UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING
127.0.0.1:6666 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
No masters detected
127.0.0.1:6666: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:03:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
127.0.0.1:6666: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=1, wr=0, async=1, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=1
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 2...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 127.0.0.1:6666 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
127.0.0.1:6666 returned, but incorrectly
127.0.0.1:6666 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
No masters detected
127.0.0.1:6666: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:03:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
127.0.0.1:6666: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=1, wr=0, async=5, socks=3; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 1...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 127.0.0.1:6666 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond...
127.0.0.1:6666 returned, but incorrectly
127.0.0.1:6666 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET
No masters detected
127.0.0.1:6666: Standalone v2.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:03:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
127.0.0.1:6666: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=1, wr=0, async=8, socks=4; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
```

Comment: I am investigating a few separate reports of connect failures - I expect this is related

Comment: Tried with 1.0.297. Seems you've changed something related with retry logic but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem using the nuget package directly. I've cloned the StackExchange.Redis repo and created a new DLL with the included bash command for mono:

```
./monobuild.bash
```

Referenced the resulting DLL and it worked flawlessly on OSX with the exact code that you've placed on the question.

Comment: I could confirm that rebuilding StackExchange.Redis in Mono helps (I did it on Windows with Xamarin Studio targeting local Mono installation)

Comment: I can confirm, I just had to do the same for an App running under Ubuntu 14.4.  Building from the mono repo, then copying the DLL over the one used in the project build resolved the issue.

Comment: I still get error using this method on OSX. test under the StackExchange.Redis  seem all passed. but still get "faulted: UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection"

Answer (score 8):

As others stated, StackExchange.Redis has problems connecting to the server on mono, and you have to build a custom assembly from the source, targeting Mono.
So I created a nuget package from the mono build of the library using *monobuild.bash*. You can use it as a direct replacement for the original **StackExchange.Redis** on mono.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Mono/

As we are using the package in our server application, I will be updating it regularly.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: @kleopatra the link is not a reference, it is a package I've made to be able to use **StackExchange.Redis** on **Mono**, and thought it would be useful to anyone having this issue.

Comment: I'm upvoting this since it solved my problem under Mono without spending more than a minute on it. Thanks for the work @LordHippo